# What's wrong with this ruby on rails migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to migrate ruby on rails application from one machine to another and when I type 
Rake db:migrate it gives following error:

```
Mysql::Error: Table 'schema_migrations' already exists:
CREATE TABLE `schema_migrations` (`version` varchar(255) NOT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

what might be the possible cause..?

Comment: check your config/database.yaml and the respective schematas

Comment: Isn't the cause obvious? It says so in your error message: "Table 'schema_migrations' already exists"

Comment: schema_migrations is not a part of the tables i use..Its the inbuilt table that rake/rails uses to carryout the database migrations.

Answer (score 8):

As mentioned by Bohdan...

or

```
rake db:migrate:reset
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi try `rake db:drop rake db:create rake db:migrate`

Comment: Please note that this will drop the info in your DB.

Answer (score 1):

In my case just dropping and creating database didn't help. Try restarting **mysql** server also:

```
/etc/init.d/mysqld restart
/etc/init.d/mysql restart
service mysqld restart
```

(depending on what OS you run), and then:

```
rake db:reset && rake db:test:clone
```

P.S. If you're using any preloaded like **zeus** or **guard**, try running without it.